# Why is there no web standards for charts?

Tags: web, standards

Charts are a pretty common thing on the Internet. So that made me wonder why there are still not some web standards for the charts?

I thought that it would be cool if we had some sort of built-in library that would create charts in your browser that would be the same all over the internet, just like `<input type="text">`, which looks the same almost everywhere.

Comment: good idea! but why stop at only one standard? https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/

Comment: Just google for "Javascript chart library", see what you get and then try to find a common ground for a standard among the results. I am pretty sure you end up at [this XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: For static graphs, generate SVG server-side.

Answer (score 2):

I think charts despite being very common are too specific for being a standard in a language.

There are really **a lot** of different ways to show charts, and it gets worse when you add interactivity.

In my opinion this belongs more in a package then in a standard.

To give an example why something that is used on lots of sites doesn’t make it a good standard by definition: there are a lot of pages with comments sections: should we also standardize those?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not sure if they are too specific, the only difference that I usually see is labels and stylings. Most of the time you just need to pass some data.